# Grab values of other fields from webhook of tawk to

Tags: php, webhooks, tawk.to

We have create a custom form while chatting with our users on twak to [image: check image]

Now using the webhook, we are able to grab the Question field and name field but we are unable to grab the phone field.

here is their [documentation](https://developer.tawk.to/webhooks/), but they are useless!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
To solve it, I utilize the Tawkto JavaScript API instead of Webhook.

Please refer to -  https://www.tawk.to/javascript-api/#onOfflineSubmit

All the form items should be found in the questions arrays of data parameter.